# IPV6 configuration issue in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

Currently, i have been working on IPV6 configuration. I am new to IPV4 and IPV6.

Could you please give me the brief explanation about the configuration of IPV6 in Ubuntu 18.04?

If i ping to google, i was getting "**connect: Network is unreachable**"

So, please help me to resolve this issue.

Best Regards

Akash.

Comment: Please add more details from your current network configuration (`ip addr show`). Is IPv4 working?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command `ip` to configure IPv4/IPv6 on your interfaces.

```
ip -6 addr add <ipv6address>/<prefixlength> dev <interface>
```

But your gateway (Box/Router/...) has to support IPv6 and had IPv6 routes. If you has access to your default gateway I suggest you to check if IPv6 is supported.

If you really want to use IPv6 you can use IPv6 Tunnel Broker (6to4).